# Validation error with no matching global declaration for root schema

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I know there's alot of instances of these errors but these kinds of validation errors don't make much sense to me

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Artwork">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="media" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="created" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="display" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

I tried switching out the schema name but that didn't do anything. Also do I need to show the XML file to solve this problem? The only code I have in there is the one to link it to the same schema 
The name spaces seem to be fine to me.. This is the XML

```
`
<Schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="artwork.xsd">

<Artworks>
 <Artwork>
     <Title>Xtreme Air</Title>
     <Media>Glass Sculpture</Media>
     <Description>An amazing work that uses glass balloon shaps to illustrate a rainbow of balloons circuling a glass earth.</Description>
     <Created>April 2010</Created>
     <Display>Orlando Museum of Arts</Display>
  </Artwork>
</Artworks>
</Schema>
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following XML/XSD pair. You would need to update the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` value with the XSD file location in your environment.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Artworks xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///e:/Temp/Artwork.xsd">
    <Artwork>
        <Title>Xtreme Air</Title>
        <Media>Glass Sculpture</Media>
        <Description>An amazing work that uses glass balloon shaps to illustrate a rainbow of balloons circuling a glass earth.</Description>
        <Created>April 2010</Created>
        <Display>Orlando Museum of Arts</Display>
    </Artwork>
</Artworks>
```

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Artworks">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Artwork"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Artwork">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Media" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Created" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Display" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Never thought of doing it like that, awesome thanks!

Comment: But what about if i want to add additional elements to the XML file ?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. You would need to make modifications to the XSD to accommodate it.

Comment: I tried adding in a max0ccurs=unbounded but that didn't work, saw that you can only do that if the element isn't directly related to the global element

Comment: You can create a new post, and specify there what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

There are two main causes for this error.

1. Namespaces. Check that the namespace in your instance document matches the target namespace of the schema.
2. API issues: there are many ways you can invoke schema validation and there are many mistakes you can make when doing so.

With so little information, that's all I can really say.

Comment: I added the xml to the question but the name spaces seem fine to me unless the element  artworks is the issue?

Comment: The top level element in your instance document is called (oddly) `Schema`, and your schema does not have a declaration of that element.

Comment: That counts as an element ? I thought that would be the defining of the schema and the first element would be artworks

Comment: I don't know where you got that idea from.

Comment: Took off schema and made the top level element artworks and it still gave the same error  so i'm assuming that makes it an API issue ?

Comment: If your instance says `artworks` and your schema says `Artworks`, then they don't match. Otherwise, yes, it's an issue of how you are invoking the validation.